# Setting up Flutter on Macbook M1

Tags: flutter

Every time I do command Flutter Run -v, on my new Macbook M1, I receive this error. I have tried it on all simulators and real devices and get the same error.

Macbook Pro 2020 M1 Chip
Memory 8GB

Visual Studio Code
Version 1.56.2

Flutter
Flutter 2.2.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b22742018b (11 days ago) • 2021-05-14 19:12:57 -0700
Engine • revision a9d88a4d18
Tools • Dart 2.13.0

Please can someone help me resolve this?

````
                     Command line invocation:
                         /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -configuration Debug
VERBOSE_SCRIPT_LOGGING=YES
                         -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner
BUILD_DIR=/Users/gallands/Documents/churchnotesappflutter/build/ios
                         -sdk iphonesimulator

SCRIPT_OUTPUT_STREAM_FILE=/var/folders/67/cvjn_r316hlffszflrqp9bcc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.yzQ1OM/flutter_build_log_pi
                         pe.LjXr4X/pipe_to_stdout FLUTTER_SUPPRESS_ANALYTICS=true COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO
-showBuildSettings
                     
                     Build settings from command line:
                         BUILD_DIR = /Users/gallands/Documents/churchnotesappflutter/build/ios
                         COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE = NO
                         FLUTTER_SUPPRESS_ANALYTICS = true
                         SCRIPT_OUTPUT_STREAM_FILE =

/var/folders/67/cvjn_r316hlffszflrqp9bcc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.yzQ1OM/flutter_build_log_pipe.LjXr4X/pipe_to_stdout
                         SDKROOT = iphonesimulator14.4
                         VERBOSE_SCRIPT_LOGGING = YES
                     
                     
                     objc[7400]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x20838c188) and ??
(0x113e8c2b8). One of
                     the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
                     objc[7400]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x20838c1d8) and ?? (0x113e8c308).
One of the two will
                     be used. Which one is undefined.
                       Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -configuration Debug VERBOSE_SCRIPT_LOGGING=YES
-workspace
                       Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner
BUILD_DIR=/Users/gallands/Documents/churchnotesappflutter/build/ios -sdk
                       iphonesimulator

SCRIPT_OUTPUT_STREAM_FILE=/var/folders/67/cvjn_r316hlffszflrqp9bcc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.yzQ1OM/flutter_build_log_pipe
                       .LjXr4X/pipe_to_stdout FLUTTER_SUPPRESS_ANALYTICS=true COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO
-showBuildSettings
[ +152 ms] "flutter run" took 399,923ms.
[ +103 ms] 
                    #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
                    #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:663:9)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1043:27)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:196:13)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
                    (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:232:5)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    
                    
[ +307 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 268ms
[   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] exiting with code 1 ```
````

Comment: What is your purpose of use `Flutter Run -v,` ? if you want get version you can use `flutter --version` , if you want run on simulator or emulator,  `flutter run lib/main.dart`. See this https://flutter.dev/docs/reference/flutter-cli . You can setup vs code to run by run or debug button (https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=vscode)